# How to launch Preview programmatically with fork and execv?

Tags: c, macos

I'm trying to launch Preview on OSX using fork and execv. When I use fork and execv on Preview the icon pops up in the dock, but nothing is displayed on the screen. The console also displays the two error messages below.

```
4/20/16 12:18:23.276 PM iconservicesagent[319]: -[ISGenerateImageOp generateImageWithCompletion:] Failed to composit image for descriptor <ISBindingImageDescriptor: 0x7f85aa50b890>.
4/20/16 12:18:23.276 PM quicklookd[1959]: Error returned from iconservicesagent: (null)
```

Below is some code to reproduce the problem, note you will have to replace
the hardcoded file path in the `args` array to a valid pdf file path for your system.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid = 0;
    int32_t rtrn = 0;

    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        char * const args[] = {"/users/nah/desktop/file.pdf", NULL};

        rtrn = execv("/Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview", args);
        if(rtrn < 0)
        {
            printf("Can't execute target program: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            _exit(-1);
        }

        _exit(0);
    }
    else if(pid > 0)
    {
        int32_t status = 0;

        while(waitpid(-1, &status, 0) > 0)
        {

        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Can't create child proc: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return (-1);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

However If I replace all the fork and execv code and use `system(3)` like in the example below, Preview opens and displays just fine and there are no error messages in console. So how do I launch Preview using fork and execv instead using `system(3)` or having to use Objective-C?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid = 0;
    int32_t rtrn = 0;

    rtrn = system("/Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview /users/nah/desktop/file.pdf");
    if(rtrn < 0)
    {
        printf("System: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return (-1);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set the additional arguments that the Mac OS X application system supplies to `main()`, but you shouldn't be doing any of this:

Preview may or may not be the default PDF viewer for the system it's running on, and if it is not, congratulations, you now have a bewildered and possibly angry user.

If you're dead set on not using Objective-C, what you'll want to do is `system("open /path/to/file.pdf");`. This will take care of all the tricky business of figuring out *what* application to use, *where* it is and *how* to launch it.

Comment: This is for a fuzzer, I specifically want to launch and test Preview so I'm not worried about users, also I don't want to wait for Preview which using system() does.

Comment: @2trill2spill `open` should return control pretty quickly, but if it's not quick enough, you could try `system("open /file.pdf &")`; should be even quicker.

Comment: The reason I want to use fork is so I have the pid of Preview so I can kill it right after launching, how can I get the pid using system() or otherwise kill Preview.

Comment: @2trill2spill I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do: Let's back up a few steps. What exactly are you trying to achieve in the first place?

Comment: Specifically I'm trying to test Preview using a technique called fuzzing. So I mutate a file and then I want Preview to try running it. When Preview is done launching I want to kill it so that Preview doesn't stay running forever. Then you repeat the whole process until Preview crashes or your kernel panics.

Comment: @2trill2spill Ah, I see. In this case, it sounds as if open should do the job admirably: Instead of closing and re-opening Preview on each new file, simply keep calling open. If Preview is already open, the file will be sent off to preview, and loaded. The design of the application (if it's well-behaved, which is not an unreasonable assumption), means that opening the application and then a file and _just_ opening a file are identical processes once the application is open; and the application opens completely prior to actually loading anything.

Comment: I tried calling open in a loop and there is two problems with that, first If I don't kill Preview each time while feeding it corrupted files it's bound to get in a weird state and if it does crash it will be hard to reproduce because it's not one file causing the crash it's a series of files. Secondly when I keep calling open on different files the screen fills up with Preview windows and eventually grinds to a halt when I run low on memory. So I really need to be able to kill Preview in between each test run.

Comment: @2trill2spill Pivoting into a Cocoa application using execv isn't so simple; it sounds like what you really want is to leverage Objective-C in this case: Have a loop that spawns instances of Preview using, for instance, `system("open -nF -a Preview testfile.pdf")`; register with the system notification center and watch for "Document Opened" notifications from Preview, and kill the applications using the info from the notification. After all, using execv _already_ leaves your application in a weird state.